# Show that the maps $X_k$ $\rightarrow \bigvee_j X_j$ are embeddings

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A topological embedding is a homeomorphism onto its image i.e let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ a topological embedding is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $f(X)$ given with the subspace topology from Y.
The question is whether $X_k$ $\rightarrow \bigvee_j X_j$ are always embeddings?

I started out with showing that $X_k$ for $0 \le k \le j$ is contained in $\bigvee_j X_j$ since by definition $\bigvee_j X_j$ identifies the base points only to a new base points (under the assumption that the newly identified base point is in fact in X which I think is true in general because of the equivalence relation) and is the disjoint union of the two spaces.Next I need to show that there exists a homemorphism between those two. I am stuck here because I cannot figure out the topology on $\bigvee_j X_j $ and later prove the homeomorphism. (for a homeomorphism $f$ to exist $f$ should be continuous and open i.e $f^{-1}$ should be continuous there does exist a injection because $0 \le k \le j$ the continuity of $f$ is guaranteed as only one point is being identified with all the base point(s) which is in $\bigcap_{r = 0}^{j} X_r$ and vice versa for the inverse but I think that this argument is wrong. It would be great if someone could point out the mistake as well )

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that if $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ then an embedding is injective and continuous which in this case it is due to the ,,canonical'' inclusion(s) makes it an embedding this was on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding)